# what do we call it if write the same method twice in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was just trying to explore oops concept in ruby

inheritance using mixins

overloading(not exactly) as var arg passing

i just wanted to what do we call this in OOPS terms

```
class Box
   def method1(str)
      puts "in old method 1"
   end

   def method1(str)
      puts "in new method 1"
   end

end

# create an object
box = Box.new

box.method1("asd")
```

this is my ruby class , obviously the one defined second gets executed ,
but I am looking for any expert comprehension from SO over this

Comment: It's called method overwrite. Overload doesn't exist in ruby.

Comment: @jokklan : shouldn't it be creating some warning , to modify previous definition , rather than redefining or rewriting

Comment: That's up for discussion ;)! But ruby doesn't warn you, no. It's very normal in ruby to overwrite methods, we do it all the time in rails for example! So if ruby warned us all the time, would we see a lot of warnings :)

Comment: @jokklan : in rails , overwriting happens in case of overwriting scaffolding methods , right ???

Comment: Scaffolding method should just be changed, there is no need to overwrite inside the same class (like your example above). But if you ever go through the rails source code would you see that a lot of the internal classes overrides methods through modules and inheritance. That's how inheritance works in ruby :)

Comment: @jokklan : I have some problem creating domain relationship in my first rails application , need help ,would you be available through chat or mail ??

Comment: Sure, click the following link to [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31753/discussion-between-jokklan-and-hussain-akhtar-wahid)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Box
   def method1(str="")
      puts "in old method 1"
   end
end
```

Pass default value

Comment: this will create a method with default parameter , i just wanted explnation , defining same method again , with different definition body , what do we call it , why is it allowed , things like that , what phenoma it relates in terms of OOPS concept

Answer (score 0):

Overloading means a class may have same method name with either different number parameter or different parameter types. Ref [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)

This is the case in most of the programming language, but `in Ruby overloading doesn't exist` as ruby is more concerned on the method calling on the parameters instead of the type of parameters. Ref [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

for ex:-

```
def add(a, b)
     a + b
end
# Above method will work for the each of the following
# add(2, 3)
# add("string1", "string2")
# add([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

So, One must wondering how we will achieve Overloading in Ruby, and answer would be

```
   def some_method(param1, param2 = nil) 
     #Some code here
   end
   # We can call above method as 
   # 1. some_method(1)
   # 2. some_method(1, 2)
```

OR

```
   def some_method(param1, param2 = nil, param3 = nil) 
     #Some code here
   end
   # We can call above method as 
   # 1. some_method(1)
   # 2. some_method(1, 2)
   # 3. some_method(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: :yeah I had pretty much the same idea , but defining the same method again , and previous one is discarded , does that co relate any OOPS concept , about overloading ,i am pretty much clear , thanx for your explanation , but I am concerned with the phenomena where we write the same method with a new definition , methods are not direct objects , so its not like simply referring to different object of the same class , so whats happening there in the class body